# Why do comments not support HTML ampersand codes?

Tags: feature-request, comments

I find myself citing the C standard very frequently in answers to questions about C. If I am referring to a particular section of the standard, I can use the HTML escape sequence `&sect;` to generate a § symbol, so I can say things like:

> According to § 1.2.3p4 of the C Standard, `x` does `y`

However, this does not work in comments (the unescaped `&sect;` remains in the comment), though I find myself wanting to cite the standard in comments once in a while as well. While I am able to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0167</kbd> to insert the symbol, is there any reason for this difference in behavior, other than that the site developers simply forgot to add it?

Comment: MSE duplicate: [Allow HTML entities in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193468/allow-html-entities-in-comments)

Comment: Easy workaround: switch to an Azerty keyboard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY#/media/File:Belgian_keyboard_layout.png

Comment: § - it's utf8, surely you can just copy/pasta whatever character you want into the comment?

Comment: Comments don't support <em>any</em> html markup, it's not just entity escapes.

Comment: I think this should be the other way around: why can I write HTML entities in posts? What happens if I want to write &sect; in a post? 

Comment: @ThomasEdwards You will have to use &amp;sect; 

Comment: HTML entities are extremely convenient on Windows and Linux. Macs have the lovely meta-key combinations for commonly used special characters, but you don’t get this elsewhere. There are the Alt-numpad shortcuts, but they aren’t mnemonic so who can remember them? Besides not all keyboards have number pads, especially notebooks. I use &mdash, &ndash, &nbsp, and &hellip all the time. I can also see the same common use for &sect as you. I would definitely be in favor of adding support for this.

Comment: @CodyGray: For Linux, enable a compose key to get Compose - - - = mdash, Compose - - . = ndash, Compose Space Space = nbsp, and Compose . . = hellip. (§ is Compose S O).